# Automating Eclipse DS-5 , by command line

Tags: eclipse, automation, command-line-interface, ds-5

Can I invoke Eclipse (DS-5), by command line (multiple invokations are acceptable, if I cannot stack commands) to:

1. build my project lcoally
2. load my project to target
3. run my application (capturing outpust is "nice to have", but not "must have")

Obviously, I am thinking of Conitnuous Integration, and invoking this from Jenkins.